# Is there a verb that means you "belong to a political ideology"?

Tags: word-request

I think you can use the verb is, as in "she is far-left", but is there a verb that's more specific, because whenever I use the verb "is" I might not get understood by everyone especially if the person I talk to is not a native English speaker.

For example:

> She ___ the far-left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> She **supports** the far left.
>
> She is **a** [strong/ardent] **supporter of** the far left.
>
> She is **a woman of** the far left.

You would likely be explaining what "the far left" means rather than why you used "is". A person familiar with the left–right political spectrum won't find any of these sentences difficult to understand.